# The representation of closed set

Tags: general-topology

We already know that closed set is the complement of open set.

*But* I want to know the representation of closed set without the fact above in the usual topology.

For instance, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed due to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ can be represented by the union of one point sets $\{n\}$
(*I don't want to use the fact that* "the union of open intervals $(n, n+1)$ is open").

Comment: All caps is considered shouting, and is quite rude. Please use [normal formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for emphasis. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX.

Comment: What do you mean by the usual topology?  On what set?

Comment: Ah, I have a omitting mistake! Usual topology is defined on the real number R.

Comment: All sets are unions of one point sets. Not all sets are closed. So this is not an argument for closedness at all (it only works for finite unions, and then only in spaces where one points sets are actually closed (the so-called $T_1$ spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one representation: **A closed set is the set with all its accumulations.**

Note that $Z$ is closed not because that it is the union of one point set. If a set is a finite union of one point set in the $T_1$ space, then it must be closed. However, if it is a countble union of one point set, it need not be closed.

> **Example:** $\mathbb R$ with usual topology, the subset $\mathbb Q$ is the union of one point set, however it is not closed.

Comment: Thanks! :) I have one more question! How to check this: if C is closed, then f(C) is also closed. (i.e. f is a closed map)

Comment: I wanna the closedness of f(C). It is not easy to show ;(

Comment: @hobin That should be posted as a separate, new question.

Comment: @hobin: You are welcome! It is the definition of closed map.

Answer (score 0):

This comes out of Klaus Janich's Topology:

Alternative Definition for Topological Spaces:

A topological space is a pair$(X,\mathscr{A})$ consisting of a set $X$ and a set $\mathscr{A}$ of subsets of $X$ called closed sets such that the following hold:

A1. Any Intersection of closed sets is closed

A2. The union of any two closed sets is closed

A3.X and $\emptyset$ are closed.

Comment: Sorry, but I know this definition. There is  a solution I want above.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can look at Kuratowski closure axioms.